# Conditional y-axis label depending on input

Tags: shiny, dygraphs

I am trying to change the y-axis label based on the input.  I am using dygraphs and Shiny. My guess is that `input$type` is not correct, but I'm unsure...  Any help is appreciated!

```
if (input$type== 'Power'){
  dygraph(TempData, main = "Battery Data") %>%
  dyAxis("y", label = "Watts")
}
if (input$type== 'Current'){
  dygraph(TempData, main = "Battery Data") %>%
  dyAxis("y", label = "Amps")
  }
dygraph(TempData, main = "Temperature") %>%
dyAxis("y", label = "Temp (C)")


  })

})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Solved!  The fix is below:

      if (colnames(Data1xts$Watts) == "Watts"){
        dygraph(TempData, main = "Battery Data") %>%
        dyAxis("y", label = "Watts (W)")
      }
    if (colnames(Data1xts$Volts) == "Volts"){
      dygraph(TempData, main = "Battery Data") %>%
      dyAxis("y", label = "Volts (V)")
    }
    else 
      dygraph(TempData, main = "Battery Data") %>%
      dyAxis("y", label = "Temp (C)")

  })

})
```